# Why was "Joining the Mile High Club (MHC) - Can I get into trouble?" closed?

Tags: discussion, scope

The question [Easiest way to join the Mile High Club (MHC)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3677/easiest-way-to-join-the-mile-high-club-mhc) is closed, as “not a real question”.

I don't understand why; [Joel's explanation](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3677/easiest-way-to-join-the-mile-high-club-mhc#comment4631_3677) doesn't help me:

> I closed this as "not a real question" because it's not an actual question somebody actually has. Stack works best when it's used to get the answers to questions people are actually facing, not for chit-chatty conversation.

Er, what? How is “I want to join the Mile High Club” (i.e. I want to have sex on a plane) not a real question, a problem to be solved?

Answer (score 7):

It's perfectly reasonable to vote for it to be reopened.  I imagine you wouldn't be alone...

However, there are two problems that I see with it, which would probably need fixing.

1) "Easiest" - is subjective

2) "Recommend a business" - is bordering on subjective, and is different to "Recommend arts museums".

However with some rewording by @Roflcopter, to make it possible to be objectively answered, would certainly reduce the chances of it being closed again.

Comment: I did vote back then (and so did at least 2 other people IIRC); my vote is long expired. This isn't a shopping question: it's not asking for a specific airline or anything like that. Would you feel better if “easiest way” was replaced by “cheapest way that doesn't lend me in legal trouble”?

Comment: Well that would remove the subjective nature to some extent.  But it wasn't me who closed it, I was merely pointing out some potential problems which may have led to it being closed in the past or future, if it were to be reopened.

Comment: I reworded it again. But I have the same problem. My reopen vote is long expired :(

Answer (score 6):

As it stands right now, the question translates to "What is the cheapest / easiest way to have sex with someone on an airplane?" Which in itself is what I would consider 'not a real question' for Travel.SE. Just because it's referred to as 'Mile High Club' doesn't change the fact what the question is asking about. (Hint: there isn't any *actual* club for it, it's just an euphemism.) Anyone could similarly then ask "What is the cheapest / easiest way to have sex in place X?" - which would *also* be off-topic / not a real question.

My suggestion for an edit would be to edit the question to ask instead: is this legal to do so, or even if it is, then will an airline ban me from flying with them / call air marshals etc. THAT I would consider to be a valid question.

Comment: Maybe the text is a little bit misleading, but there I'm only explaining the background. The actual questions are: 1) Is there any special plane designed for that purpose? 2) Do I get into trouble when doing this on a regular plane? So in my opinion the question is already in the form you suggested.

Comment: I've already explained why 'cheapest/easiest' is the wrong question to ask here. Just reword the question as suggested here and it should be fine for reopening.

Comment: I see, so I made a last attempt to edit it again.