# Mile High question needs to be cleaned up

Tags: discussion, wrong-answers

Our question about [Joining the Mile High Club](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/3677/444) was originally closed, then reopened [after some editing](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/631/444).

After the edit, the [top-voted answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/3683/444) no longer matches the question, and the [second-highest voted and accepted answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/5630/444) seems somewhat border-line.

Both answers match the earlier, too-subjective-to-survive version of the question.

I flagged the first answer as not-an-answer, although admittedly, I felt a bit crummy for doing so, since it was a reasonable answer at the time it was written. My flag was "disputed".

I still feel like *something* ought to happen to the question/answer mismatch.

I'm just not exactly sure what...  (And obviously, this should have been handled at the time the question was originally edited and re-opened.)

Comment: Edit the answers to put in a note -- "This answered a previous version of the question"? I read it earlier and the answers didn't strike me as not answering, but on rereading it I see what you mean. It's probably just one of those things, there's good info in the answers. Maybe re-submit the question again?

Comment: Could you not reword one line of the question from `Could I get into trouble if I do this on a regular plane [examples of possible trouble]` to `Can this be done on a regular plane without risking trouble such as [examples of possible trouble]`? This would still be not subjective - it's "avoiding risk" not "d'ya reckon I could get away with it?" - and fits all answers and the original intent.

Answer (score 2):

Where an Accepted A does not match the OP as asked I suggest the author of the accepted A adjusts the Q (as little as possible, unless generally improving it) to match. I have done so a few times myself (mainly or only on SO) and not had any complaints - mind you, once OP has an answer on SO they rarely show any further interest in the post.

This is a somewhat special case since Accepted A was written by OP. However I still think Q & A should match and since a mod was the author of both perhaps all the more reason to "set a good example".