# Mile High Club Revisited

Tags: discussion, support

This is not the first META question about the 'mile high club'.  See [Why was "Joining the Mile High Club (MHC) - Can I get into trouble?" closed?](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/631/why-was-the-mile-high-club-question-closed)

Is it OK to ask this question...

A friend wants to celebrate the new year by doing a 'mile high club' lark (i.e., coitus at cruising altitude).  He has a partner.  Is there a commercial flight that offers a double bed?  He doesn't care where it leaves from or lands, he is happy to pay the cost of getting to the departure airport and returning from wherever the flight lands.  Yes, for sure he could charter a jet but this dampens (if not obviates altogether) the 'mile high club' experience.  Hence it needs to be a commercially bookable flight, with a commercially bookable double bed on new years eve.

---

I have looked on the net but came up dry (to coin a phrase). Is the question too WANTA for us? Too offensive to our user base?  Or is it OK?

Comment: I believe Singapore airlines offers a bed, with champagne....but I think achieving mile high status is technically banned ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo I didn't know it was banned. Good thing I used META first. I linked to a question http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3677/joining-the-mile-high-club-mhc-can-i-get-into-trouble that still appears to be visible. I suppose we should delete it and any other stragglers.

Comment: @GayotFow no I said I believe it's banned, I don't have a reference for that :)  And that was just for Singapore Airlines, who knows what other airlines might have.

Comment: And from the linked question - this airline seems to allow it: http://www.blick.ch/erotik/sex-ueber-den-wolken-bei-dieser-airline-rumpelts-nicht-nur-wegen-der-luftloecher-id1770801.html

Comment: @MarkMayo were you saying the topic is banned here on TSE or the act itself is banned by the carrier? Part of the 'mile high club' thrill (I suspect) is the concealment and surreptitious nature needed to execute. Hence the requirement that it's a commercial flight.  If it's also banned, that would be icing on the cake (if you'll forgive the expression).

Comment: Banned by the carrier. I just remember it from a press release when the bed + champagne deal was announced.

Comment: http://onemileatatime.img.boardingarea.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Emirates-A380-First-Class-077.jpg

Comment: @chx priceless, ta

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would certainly be about Travel (which is more than can be said for many here!).

I take it you would not be seeking users here to arrange the booking, just advise what is available, where. That's not a WANTA issue.

I see nothing offensive about asking about double beds a mile up in the sky given that such [exist](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/travel/article-2620529/The-luxurious-plane-world-offers-three-room-suite-personal-butler-gourmet-food-cost-12-500-ONE-WAY.html) and are legal - if criminally expensive ;) .

There is something by way of a precedent: [What is the etiquette around sex in hotel beds?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52651/what-is-the-etiquette-around-sex-in-hotel-beds)